# Realtek RTL8201 CL/PL NETWORK DRIVER

Tags: drivers

I had to format my friend's computer & she didn't have the motherboard cd so I have to download the network driver from the Internet!
I need Realtek RTL8201 CL/PL network driver but I can't find the right link to download it.

Where can I download it from ?

Answer (score 0):

[Realtek mentions](http://www.realtek.com/faqs/faqsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=1&PFid=1&Level=3) you have to rely on your motherboard vendor for the drivers

> Q9: Why don't I find RTL8201x driver
>   on the website?
>
> A9:  RTL8201,
>   RTL8201BL, RTL8201CL, RTL8201CP,
>   RTL8201N and RTL8211B(L) are all
>   PHYceiver. That is a driverless
>   hardware device. Software driver are
>   relative to Network controller ( MAC )
>   which is integrated into chipset in
>   such case mostly. Please contact your
>   mother board maker or chipset
>   manufacturer to obtain proper driver
>   support.